# inputRejected signal not found

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlineedit, qt-signals

ALL,

```
connect(this, &QLineEdit::inputRejected,
        this, &this::my_handler);
```

Qt 5.7.1 on Gentoo Linux

```
error: 'inputRejected' is not a member of 'QLineEdit'
```

Documentation doesn't give any restrictions on that signal.

What is the problem?

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[inputRejected()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#inputRejected) has been recently introduced in [Qt 5.12](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/dist/changes-5.12.0/?h=v5.12.0#n349) so you'll have to update your version of Qt.

- [QTBUG-57448] Added inputRejected() signal for when a key press is not
   accepted by the QLineEdit. For instance, when an invalid key is
   pressed for a validator set.

Comment: Yes, I figured that much. Did this: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-72386. Do you know if there is a way to do something when the max length of the text is reached for an older Qt version? Apparently catching textChanged doesn't help. TIA!