# Catching QLineEdit overflowing

Tags: qt5, qlineedit

According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53671627/qt5-inputrejected-signal-not-found) the special signal to catch the situation where the user types more characters into QLineEdit than the max length limit was added in 5.12.

However, is there a way to catch this situation in Qt 5.{0-11} and perform some action - namely inform the user about it?

Comment: I don't know if this is useful or not, but [here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qwidgetlinecontrol.cpp.html) you have the source code where you can see when the lineedit emits the signal.

Comment: @Tarod, thank you. Looks like I will have to reimplement paste() function if its possible.

Comment: @Tarod, just one question - the link you provided is for the 5.12 with the newly introduced rejectInput signal. Do you have a link to the previous version code?

Comment: Well, the idea should be to implement your own signal instead of rejectInput.